# Отключение клиентского сокета от QTcpServer

Tags: c++, qt, qtcpsocket

Есть сервер и клиентское приложение. При подключении клиента к серверу происходят следующие действия:

```
//client - указатель на QTcpSocket
client = server->nextPendingConnection();
connect(client, SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SLOT(SockLost()));
connect(client, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(SockReadyRead()));
```

Проблема в том, что, по логике вещей, при вызове `client->close()` или `client->disconnectFromHost()` у клиентского приложения должен быть вызывал сигнал `disconnected()`, но вместо него вызывается сигнал `error()`, но по факту же никакой ошибки не произошло, я ведь просто отключил клиента от сервера.

Это я что то делаю не так? Или так и должно быть?

Comment: Судя по коду, который Вы привели, `client` является объектом сокета на серверной стороне. Так для кого всё-таки инициируется выполнение `close()` и `disconnectFromHost()`?

Comment: Ну а как тогда корректным способом отключить клиента от сервера со стороны сервера, чтобы у клиента не был вызван сигнал `error()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Метод `QAbstractSocket::disconnectFromHost()` должен вызываться только на стороне клиента, поскольку именно она вызывает перед этим `QAbstractSocket::connectToHost()`. Соответственно реакция на закрытие соединения приведёт к получению ожидаемого сигнала `disconnected()`.

Поскольку `QAbstractSocket` наследуется от класса `QIODevice`, то метод `close()` доступен также и для сокетов. Разница между `close()` и методом `disconnectFromHost()` состоит в том, что последний сначала отправит данные, что пока ещё не успели уйти в сеть, и лишь затем закроет соединение.

Закрытие соединения на серверной стороне - это в общем случае внештатная ситуация. Сервер предназначен, как пионер, всегда быть готовым к труду и, если к нему подключился клиент, быть готовым в максимально сжатые сроки выполнить предусмотренную операцию. Когда же именно сервер начинает решать, общаться ли с клиентом или нет, то логично предположить, что либо клиент лицом не вышел, либо случилось нечто из ряда вон выходящее. Соответственно, сокету на клиентской стороне необходимо понимать, что именно воля серверной стороны явилась определяющей при принятии решения о закрытии соединения.

Разумеется, что за оправданностью нарушения обычного поведения для серверной стороны в каждом конкретном случае отвечает автор кода, для которого это по некоторым причинам может быть вполне оправданно. Но суть в том, что фреймворк должен следовать правилам, приемлемым для стандартных ситуаций. Соответственно приравнивание случая разрыва соединения по инициативе серверной стороны к ошибке для клиента - это вполне себе нормально. Впрочем, насильно никто не заставляет считать флаг `QAbstractSocket::RemoteHostClosedError` в качестве неустранимой препоны. В собственном слоте-обработчике всегда есть возможность сделать исключение для тех "ошибок", которые по мнению автора кода в его частном случае таковыми не являются.

Comment: Все понял, спасибо)

Comment: @WenSiL, пожалуйста!